# Excel / VBA iterate over every cell in a worksheet, compare the value, copy row to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

In my Excel-File I want to implement a custom search. Therefore I created a worksheet called "Search" - On this Table I put a TextBox, a Button and a short Info-text.
At the moment I go over every worksheet and copy the second row (Titles of my columns), then I compare the text of every cell with the searchword and if i get a match I will copy the row, where I found the match.

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False       

Dim searchword As String
searchword = Worksheets("Search").SearchTextBox.Text       

If Len(Trim(searchword)) > 0 Then       

    Worksheets("Search").Cells.Delete    

    Dim i As Long
    i = 5                       
    Dim found As Boolean

     For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets       
        Worksheet.Range("A2").EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Search").Cells(i, 1)    
        i = i + 1           
        found = False   
        For Each cell In Worksheet.UsedRange.Cells      
            If InStr(cell.Text, searchword) > 0 Then     
                cell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Search").Cells(i, 1)    
                found = True     
                i = i + 1                       
            End If
        Next
        If found = True Then
            i = i + 4               
        Else
            Worksheets("Search").Rows(i - 1).Delete   
        End If
     Next

Else
    MsgBox "Empty TextBox!", vbOKOnly, "Error"      
End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True            
End Sub
```

But when a word is multiple times in one row this code will copy this row multiple times. How can I jump to the next row if I find a match?

I'm glad for any help or idea

Comment: Use some flag to indicate that you found what you have been looking for in certain cell and break out of the loop using `Exit For` statement :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn If i break out of the loop it will stop searching in the worksheet and goes to the next one?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim searchword As String
    searchword = Worksheets("Search").SearchTextBox.Text

    If Len(Trim(searchword)) > 0 Then

        Worksheets("Search").Cells.Delete

        Dim i As Long
        i = 5
        Dim found As Boolean

        For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            Worksheet.Range("A2").EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Search").Cells(i, 1)
            i = i + 1
            found = False
            For Each Row In Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows
                For Each cell In Row.Cells
                    If InStr(cell.Text, searchword) > 0 Then
                        cell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Search").Cells(i, 1)
                        found = True
                        i = i + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            If found = True Then
                i = i + 4
            Else
                Worksheets("Search").Rows(i - 1).Delete
            End If
        Next

    Else
        MsgBox "Empty TextBox!", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this code also searches your Search worksheet, you may want to omit that sheet form the search.

Comment: If I exit the for loop, when I find a match, then I will not Look at any other row or cell in this Worksheet so it will jump straight to the next one. So it is possible, when a Keyword is in different rows on one sheet I only will get the first row....

Comment: It only exits the for loop which loops through the cells of one row, making it go to the next row when the first match is found.

Comment: You're right, on the first look I thought you only inserted a `Exit For`It Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

The answer below will:

1. Search all the sheets in the `WorkBook` which the code is placed, except the `Sheet("Search")`.
2. In each of those `Sheets` it will run through every `Row` and look for the `searchword`. If it finds the word in that row it will copy the entire row into the `Sheet("Search")`.  It will then move onto the next row of that `Sheet`.

See Code below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim CurrentRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim searchword As String
    Dim TextFoundRng As Range

    searchword = Worksheets("Search").SearchTextBox.Text

    If Len(Trim(searchword)) > 0 Then

        Worksheets("Search").Cells.Delete

        Dim i As Long
        i = 5
        Dim found As Boolean

        'Using this WorkBook instead of Active, incase another workbook is activated
        For Each CurrentSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            If CurrentSheet.Name = "Search" Then

            Else

                With CurrentSheet
                    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                End With


                'i = i + 1
                'found = False

                For CurrentRow = 2 To LastRow

                    Set TextFoundRng = CurrentSheet.Range(CurrentSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 2), _
                                                          CurrentSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, LastColumn)).Find(What:=searchword)
                    'When TextFoundRng <> nothing, it means found something'
                    If Not TextFoundRng Is Nothing Then

                        CurrentSheet.Rows(CurrentRow).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Search").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

                    End If

                Next CurrentRow

                'For Each cell In CurrentSheet.UsedRange.Cells
                '
                '    If InStr(cell.Text, searchword) > 0 Then
                '        cell.EntireRow.Copy CurrentSheet("Search").Cells(i, 1)
                '        found = True
                '        i = i + 1
                '    End If
                '
                'Next
                'If found = True Then
                '    i = i + 4
                'Else
                '    Worksheets("Search").Rows(i - 1).Delete
                'End If

            End If
        Next CurrentSheet

    Else
        MsgBox "Empty TextBox!", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    End If

    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I have kept your `Found` and `i` code in case you need it for something else, but this code does not need to use it to copy every row which has the searchword from every sheet.